# Multithreaded linq2sql applications TransactionScope difficulties

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq-to-sql, transactionscope

I've created a file processing service which reads and imports xml files from a specific directory.

The service starts several workers which will poll a filequeue for new files and uses linq2sql for dataaccess. Each workerthread has its own datacontext.

The files being processed contain several orders and each order contains several addresses (Customer/Contractor/Subcontractor)

I've defined a transactionscope around the handling of each file. This way I want to ensure that the whole file is handled correctly, or that the whole file is rolled back when an exception occurs:

```
        try
        {
            using (var tx = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
            {
                foreach (var order in orders)
                {
                    HandleType1Order(order);
                }
                tx.Complete();
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Number == SqlErrorNumbers.Deadlock)
            {
                throw new FileHandlerException("File Caused a Deadlock, retrying later", ex, true);
            }
            else
                throw;
        }
```

One of the requirements for the service is that is creates or updates found addresses in the xml files. So I've created an address service which is responsible for address management. The following piece of code gets executed for each order (within the method `HandleType1Order()`) in the xml importfile (**And thus is part of the TransactionScope for the entire file**).

```
 using (var tx = new TransactionScope())
            {

                address = GetAddressByReference(number);
                if (address != null) //address is already known
                {
                    Log.Debug("Found address {0} - {1}. Updating...", address.Code, address.Name);
                    UpdateAddress(address, name, number, isContractor, isSubContractor, isCustomer);
                }
                else
                {
                    //address not known, so create it
                    Log.Debug("Address {0} not known, creating address", number);
                    address = CreateAddress(name, number, sourceSystemId, isContractor, isSubContractor,
                                            isCustomer);
                    _addressRepository.Save(address);

                }

                _addressRepository.Flush();
                tx.Complete();
            }
```

What I'm trying to do here, is to create or update an address, with the number being unique.

The method `GetAddressByReference(string number)` returns a known address or null when an address is not found.

```
 public virtual Address GetAddressByReference(string reference)
 {
     return _addressRepository.GetAll().SingleOrDefault(a=>a.Code==reference);
 }
```

When I run the service it however creates multiple addresses with the same number. The method `GetAddressByReference()` get's called concurrently and should return a known address when a second thread executes the method with the same addressnumber, however it returns null. There is propably something wrong with my transaction boundaries, or isolationlevel, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Help is much appreciated!!

p.s. I've no problem with the transactions being deadlocked and causing a rollback, the file will just be retried when a deadlock occurs.

---

*Edit 1* Threading code:

```
        public void Work()
    {
        _isRunning = true;
        while (true)
        {
            ImportFileTask task = _queue.Dequeue(); //dequeue blocks on empty queue               
            if (task == null)
                break; //Shutdown worker when a null task is read from the queue

            IFileImporter importer = null;
            try
            {
                using (new LockFile(task.FilePath).Acquire()) //create a filelock to sync access accross all processes to the file
                {
                    importer = _kernel.Resolve<IFileImporter>();
                    Log.DebugFormat("Processing file {0}", task.FilePath);
                    importer.Import(task.FilePath);
                    Log.DebugFormat("Done Processing file {0}", task.FilePath);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(
                    "A Fatal exception occured while handling {0} --> {1}".FormatWith(task.FilePath, ex.Message), ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (importer != null)
                    _kernel.ReleaseComponent(importer);
            }

        }

        _isRunning = false;
    }
```

The above method runs in all of our worker threads. It uses Castle Windsor to resolve the FileImporter, which has a transient lifestyle (thus not shared accross threads).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post your threading code, so its difficult to say what the issue is. I'm assuming you have started DTC (Distributed Transaction Coordinator)?

Are you using a ThreadPool? Are you using the "lock" keyword?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

Comment: The transaction is not promoted to a Distributed transaction since each transaction uses only one SQLConnection. Regarding the lock keyword, yes we use synchronization, but we are trying to realize the database access synchronization using transactions (Which is the correct way of doing it, imho)